# Create Empty database using Oracle Database configuration Assistant

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle's Database Configuration Assistant tool to create a new database but once the database is created, I open it in Oracle SQL Developer, I see a lot of tables already created. Why is that? How can I create an empty database?

P.S: This is how my database tables look like after creating it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion between schema and databases.

You can never create an empty database in Oracle, since when you create a database in Oracle with DBCA tool, it creates some pre-seeded sample schemas and some System schemas with system tables.

You can create an empty schema using the `CREATE SCHEMA` command, after the database is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @vishad answear.

1. Install SQL Plus, it will ask about password which is needed later
2. Open console and type `connect`, provide username(system) and password from point 1
3. Create database with commands:

> ```
> CREATE USER "YOUR_USER" IDENTIFIED BY superPassword;
>  
> GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "YOUR_USER" ;
> GRANT "DBA" TO "YOUR_USER" ;
> GRANT "CONNECT" TO "YOUR_USER" ;
> GRANT "EXP_FULL_DATABASE" TO "YOUR_USER" ;
> GRANT "IMP_FULL_DATABASE" TO "YOUR_USER" ;
> ```

4. Connect to database with SQLDeveloper. Defaults are:

> ```
> username: YOUR_USER
> password: superPassword
> Hostname: localhost
> Port: 1521
> SID: xe
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have open sample database . Make sure that you have opened database that is create by you.

Comment: how do i make sure that?