# Oracle Database 19c Sample Schemas :: import sample from Oracle SQL Developer GUI instead of command line

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have a Microsoft background and I'm learning Oracle products.

I was able to import [Oracle Database 19c Sample Schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas) on a Docker Oracle image from command line following this [guide](https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/l/oracle-in-docker-containers-on-linux/step-5-import-sample-schemas-from-github).

I now would like to know if there is a way to import the same sample through a GUI using **Oracle SQL Developer**.

With SSMS is quite simple to import/export databases, row data, CSV, etc... but I don't see the same tool for Oracle SQL Developer.

**EDIT:**

@thatjeffsmith suggested to right click on tables > Data Import Wizard, but when I select **"db-sample-schemas-master"** I only find the samples with `.sql` files in it and `.sql` files cannot be imported with this tool

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

The .SQL files can be ran through the SQL worksheet via F5 no problem.

The sqlldr scenarios, you could rename the .dat files to .dsv files.

Right click on your table, like Sales History SH entries, choose Import Data, and [walk the wizard.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/)

But, it would be much easier to just follow the instructions as is, especially if you are new to Oracle.

Comment: Thank you @thatjeffsmith, .sql + F5 will be the path for me in this scenario. I still don't like the fact that Microsoft gives you AdventureWorks, you download it and you import it and that's it. In the other hand just finding some Oracle sample is hard and there is no such "import", they just gives you the .sql files. I find it very archaic and i hope Oracle can be more modern that this. Microsoft know how to pet the newbies, Oracle is harsh and itchy

Comment: The installer used to give you the option to install the sample schemas at the time of the database creation, I'd like to see that come back for the very reason you're describing.

Comment: ...also because I know how to run queries pressing F5 but the problem is that before I need to create an empty DB.... and apparently I cannot create an empty DB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947444/create-empty-database-using-oracle-database-configuration-assistant.
And I don't have dbca.bat because I'm on a docker image. Unpleasant situation for a newbee but I will hit hard with the hammer till the nail goes in :)